# Adding a list to another list with least typing?

Tags: java

Sorry I suspect the answer is easy but I'm getting annoyed at the way I'm currently doing this and was trying to find another way(old python habits, sorry).
I basically want to create a list of list(list has two integers) so for example it looks like this `[[0,0], [0,1],[1,2]]` and so on.

Right now the two ways I have been doing it(which I don't think is right) is the tutorial way of:

```
list1.add(data);
list1.add(more_data);
final_list_of_list.add(list1);
```

I did some digging to find another way because I'm lazy and want to do this in one shot, so I found a command that fit my needs(in terms of getting data in)

```
List final_list_of_list = new ArrayList();
final_list_of_list.add(new Point(0, 0)); //and so on..
```

The problem with point is when I look at my *beautiful* data I see the ugliness of this:

```
[java.awt.Point[x=970,y=10], java.awt.Point[x=65,y=10], java.awt.Point[x=729,y=10]
```

Surely there is a easier way to add the data and still have it look nice(like the format above in my example)?

Comment: It's not clear what the question is about - the result of calling `toString` on a list, or finding the cleanest way of creating a list. These are two entirely orthogonal things.

Comment: I guess ultimately I'm looking for something like Point that doesn't add all the extra stuff.

Comment: it's not Point that's adding the extra stuff, a large part of it is from List.

Comment: @learningJava: Do you mean "extra stuff" in the string representation? It's still not really clear what you're trying to get out of this question. Generally speaking, the string representation of a list is unimportant...

Comment: @Jochen I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I'm very new to java so sorry about this but when I print the values above it seems to be referring to java.awt.Point? Are you saying that list is adding those based on the way I'm adding them?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes I was referring to the string representation.  I'm sorry I think I'm wrong but I thought those affected my code. In python I would print data and once I knew how it looked I could do something like like data[0] or data[0], based on your comments I'm starting to think that logic doesn't apply in java?

Comment: @learningJava: you can use `data.get(0)` but the string representation really isn't terribly relevant. Some classes override `toString`, others don't - it doesn't affect what's *in* the list.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't know that. I thought the list contained what I saw.  I'll play around and try to understand it more.  Question, why do they have this in the string if its not in the list itself? If I wanted to know it was part of java.awt.Point I could just check my code so is there a purpose of having a different string output than what's actually in the list?

Comment: OK, here's the thing. EVERY class in Java has a toString() method. Some inherit the one from Object, some have their own. The toString() method of List prints
[ element1, element2, ... ]
I think, but am not certain, that it might also add the 'java.awt.Point' prefix. In any case, writing your own Point or other datastructure will give you what you need

Comment: @Jochen I understand that now thanks to Jon, I guess I'm just not sure what the point of adding the extra bits to it is.  To me it seems Pointless(pun intended) but if it was it wouldn't be there, so I guess I'm wondering why add different things to the string representation? Would a developer ever want extra strings on their data?

Comment: Yes. For example, the Eclipse debugger uses toString() to display that values of variables. It is very useful to have that extra bit of info when you inspect the contents of lists, especially if you can add stuff of different types.
Or another way of putting it, toString() in practice is often used for logging output for debugging, not for output that displays useful stuff to users of your program. And there every extra bit of info helps.

Comment: @Jochen interesting. I get it now. Its a bit different from python but I guess it makes sense for debugging(since it gives you the ability to print out individual parts of point if needed).  Thanks so much Jochen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subclass `Point` or create your own implementation and override the `toString()` method to print something prettier.  I think that would be easier than trying to work with lists of lists.

Perhaps something like this:

```
public class MyPoint {
    public final int x;
    public final int y;

    public MyPoint(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + x + "," + y + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably will find `Collections.addAll(list, ...)` useful too.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things here that don't seem clear:

a) By "looking" at your data you seem to mean printing it with toString(). If you want that to look different, you have to provide your own toString() method. Or use some other way to "look" at your data.

b) You might want to define your own class for pairs, for example as Pair, that way you will be far more flexibile that with Point (which only takes ints, IIRC). Then you should use generics for your lists, and the list you want looks like

```
List<Pair<type1, type2>> allMyData;
```

That's not exactly the least amount of typing, but the best way of programming ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can overide the point object's "tostring method." Take a look at [this](http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-tostring-method).